# What is the closed cone generated by constant and coordinate functions and closed under taking $f\mapsto\max(f,0)$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, convexity, tropical-geometry

Let $C$ be the smallest closed convex cone of functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ that contains all constant functions, all coordinate functions, and such that $\max(f,0)\in C$ whenever $f\in C$.

Is there any useful characterization of the functions lying in $C$?
It is easy to see that such functions must be convex and in addition have non-negative partial derivatives up to the second order, but I would think these conditions aren't sufficient.

Comment: It seems to me that every function in your cone is of the form $f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) = \max(a_1 x_1, a_2 x_2, \ldots, a_n x_n, -b_1 x_1, -b_2 x_2, \ldots, -b_n x_n, c)$ for some nonnegative constants $a_i$, $b_i$ and $c$. Can you give me an example of a function not of this form?

Comment: The cone only contains coordinate functions, not their opposite (if you include opposite coordinate functions the cone includes all convex functions)

Comment: Also if you add two different functions of the form you described, you might get a function that is not of this form

Comment: You're assuming that the cone is closed with respect to which topology?

Comment: @YCor let's say pointwise convergence

Comment: For $n=1$, is it correct that we obtain exactly all convex non-decreasing functions?

Comment: @Ycor yes that's correct. Starting from two dimensions things seem to get more complicated

Comment: Okay, I get it now. Interesting question.